# `'dependencies.dependency.version'` is missing in multi module inherited project though we use <dependencymanagement>

Tags: java, maven

I have a common dependency that needs to be used across different poms.Here for ex `spring-ws-core` is what I need to use on Pom A, Pom B etc .Pom A will inherit properly but when I remove the version in Pom B it is throwing issue.

Common

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>   
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId> 
        <version>5.0 RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Pom A

```
<dependecyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Common</groupId>   
            <artifactId>Common</artifactId> 
            <type>pom</type>    
            <scope>import</scope>   
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependecyManagement>

<dependencies>
```

> Note:I am not using version since it is inheriting from
>   `<dependencymangement >` centralized pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>   
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId> 
<dependency>

</dependencies>
```

> Pom B:

```
**Parent will be Pom A **

<parent>
    <groupId>Pom A</groupId>
    <artifactId>Pom A</artifactId>
    <version>someversion</version>
    <relativePath>pom A.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

> This doesn't have `<dependencymanagement>` since it should be inherited from Pom A since Pom A has `<dependecymanagement>`

Now my issue if I add any dependency without version in Pom B it is throwing  `'dependencies.dependency.version'` is missing.How to inherit to Pom B  from common is what I am looking for .If I add `<dependencymanagement>` in Pom B it is not working as expected .

Anyone can shed some light would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please make a simple example project or may be you can show the project on Github?

Comment: Sure I will upload and share the project .